# how to show id, compliantype in angular 7 with using asp.net core web api>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular7

i am using asp.net core web api for backend and angular 7 for front end .i created database using code first 
approach and then i added one more table called Complains .now i wan to return complains table id and two or three more columns from complains table using get request. then get these values in angular and show some where .

```
   //this is interface method
    Object UserComplainInformation(Complains complains);

    //this is service class which implements above interface 
     public Object UserComplainInformation(Complains complains)
            {
                var resp = new
                {
                Id = _appDbContext.Complains.FindAsync(complains.Id),
                Type =complains.Type
                };
                try
                {
                    _appDbContext.Complains.FindAsync(resp);
                    return resp;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

    //Controller 
     [HttpGet]
           // [Route("complainInformation")]
            public Object UserComplainInformation(Complains complain)
            {
                return _complains.UserComplainInformation(complain);
            }
    //angular service code
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
    import { ConfigService } from './util/config.service';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ComplainHistoryService {
      BaseUrl : string ='';
      constructor( private config:ConfigService, private http:HttpClient)  { 
        this.BaseUrl =config.getApiURI();
      }

      ngOnInit(){  }

      getUserComplainHistory(){
        return this.http.get(this.BaseUrl +'/complianInformation');
      }
    }

    //.ts file usercomplainhistory
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { ComplianHistoryService } from 'src/shared/complain-history.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-complians-history',
      templateUrl: './user-complains-history.component.html',
      styles: []
    })
    export class UserComplainsHistoryComponent implements OnInit {


      userDetails = sessionStorage.getItem('FullName');
      userComplainDetails;

      constructor(private router:Router, private complainService: ComplainHistoryService) {  }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.complainService.getUserComplainHistory().subscribe(
          res =>{
            this.userComplainDetails = res;
            console.log(res);
          },
          err =>{
            console.error(err);
          }
        )
      }
    }
    //this is html file where i want to show id and some more fields 
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>FullName : </strong>{{userDetails}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Complian Id : </strong>{{userComplianDetails}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: i am new to asp.net web api and angular 7

Comment: What's exactly your problem?

Comment: @iamdlm the problem is that i need to get complain table id and some more fields and show in angular ...